Cross-sectional area of ​a right prism with an arbitrary quadrilateral at the base without searching for cross-section points
Is there an algorithm for calculating the cross-sectional area of ​​a right prism with an arbitrary quadrilateral at the base (with known coordinates of its vertices) for a given normal to the cross-section plane (passing through the centroid of the prism) without searching for cross-section points?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If I understand correctly, you have a situation like this:

The darker blue quad is in the xy-plane, and extruded in the direction of the orange arrow, which is not perpendicular to the plane. The resulting shape (pale blue, slightly transparent) is sliced by a plane perpendicular to the orange line, resulting in the red quadrilateral. (I have to apologize for my drawing skills here...I did my best.)
And you want to know the area of the red quad.
Assuming I got all that right, let's use $u$ to denote the angle between the vertical and the orange line, so that "$u$ = 0 degrees" would be an "ordinary" prism, for which the red area would be equal to the dark-blue area of the base.
Then in general, using $B$ to denote the area of the original (dark blue) quad, and $R$ to denote the area of the sliced quad, we have
$$
R = B \cos u.
$$
Checking for $u = 0$, we get that $R = B$, which is good. If you draw a $1 \times 1$ square for your red quad (so R = 1), and tilt it 45 degrees, and imagine the sun's rays arriving in the opposite direction from the orange arrow, then the bottom blue quad will be the shadow of that square...which will have one side of length $1$, and the other of length $\sqrt{2}$, so that $B = \sqrt{2}$. The cosine of $45$ degrees is $\sqrt{2}/2$, so our formula says we should have
$$
R = B \sqrt{2}/2
$$
and plugging in $R = 1$ and $B = \sqrt{2}$, that gives
$$
1 = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2}/2
$$
which is correct. So the formula checks out in at least two cases.
